# use tlsv1.2 in mobilefirst javascript http adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I asked a similar question before and was able to use tlsv1.2 in java adapter, now I need to be able to do the same thing but in a javascript http adapter. Anyone know how to force the adapter to use tlsv1.2? This is Mobilefirst 7.0 on a mac.

Here is a code snippet of how to do it in java adapter:

```
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(null, null, null);

        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSslcontext(context);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI(baseURL));
        request.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
        json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

Don't see a way to do this in the http adapter:

```
        function getProbes(appName) {
          var input = {
          method : 'get',
          returnedContentType : 'json',
          path : "greenspot-web/rest/category/category/" + appName,
          body : {
           contentType : 'application/json',
           content : ''
          }
        };

        input.headers = headers;
        var res = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Last fall, work was done to add TLS V1.2 support when running with WebSphere, so installing the latest fix pack for 7.0 and up should enable you to do this

To write your JavaScript adapter to use TLS V1.2, the key issue is to use the WebSphere JSSEHelper API instead of the Apache HTTP client.  The Apache client cannot handle the WebSphere SSL context that is required for force the version switch.  Using JSSEHelper allows the adapter to correctly handle the WebSphere trust store and set the protocol.

Here are some links:

- [WebSphere JSSEHelper documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ssl/JSSEHelper.html)
- [Programmatically specifying an outbound SSL configuration using JSSEHelper API](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tsec_ssloutconfiguseJSSE.html?lang=en)

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the JavaScript HTTP adapter.  Maybe by invoking Java code from the JavaScript adapter? Could be. Perhaps this will help guide you to the right place: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/javascript-adapters/using-java-adapters/

Comment: Yes, I am sure I can do it by invoke the connection code in java class from javascript adapter as that is easy, but developers wanted to do it in http adapter due to redeploy issues: ...every changes on Java class may caused re-deploy war file on server...and we want to avoid this... So the questions is how will this affect all of those adapters in production that folks use when everyone gets forced to move to TLS1.2? ..and we know that is coming...

Comment: With Java adapters you can place libraries in the adapter's lib folder... you don't need to put it in the server's lib folder (you could...), thus you do not need to redeploy the war file. That's part of why Java adapters are now a thing in MobileFirst.

Comment: Thanks Idan. We can use Java adapter for this project, but not sure what this means for all of those deployed apps out there that may get told to move to TLS1.2. They will have to rewrite their adapters.